# How to simulate bi layer membrane

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to simulate a membrane that should look like this. So, when some object fall from top over the surface, it will create a hole  (circular) in the layer and bend the objects like in the animated gif. Any suggestions or hints on how and where to start.
[image]

Comment: Create a mesh with shapekeys for solid and hole state. Then add dupliverts.

Comment: Shape keys is a good choice. But how can I do it in a rectangular volume filled with these models. Is there any way to simulate it by means of applying physics.